# JqueryUi resizable issue, alsoResize expands beyond containment!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

i have this structure of DIVs

```
<div id="container">
   <div="outer">
      <div id="inner">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and i made the 'outer' div `resizable()` using this jqueryUi

```
$("#outer").resizable({ containment: 'parent', alsoResize: "#inner"  });
```

till now every thing is OK!

//////////////// **the issue** /////////////////

When i resize the outer it resize the inner with it but when it reaches the 'container' div it STOPS which is OK but the inner keep resizing with the mouse moving and exceed the 'container' and the 'outer' DIVs!!!!

can i make the 'inner' ALSO STOPS with the 'outer' when it reaches the 'container' div limits????

Thank You in advance, i know you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by setting `maxHeight` and `maxWith` for your container.

```
$("#outer").resizable({
    alsoResize: '#inner',
    containment: 'parent',
    maxHeight: 500,
    maxWidth:500
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/WV2nn/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to use alsoResize? Shouldn't you fix this by using correct markup and css?

Comment: yah i need that coz the inner is the div where my content will be 

the outer is only for holding the x button to remove the whole element

Comment: If the outer div resizes, the inner div will automatically resize with it. You don't need alsoResize for that… unless you have given the inner div a height and a width.

Comment: i just tried removing alsoResize, and the outer expanded with me but the inner didn't!!? i need them both synchronized in resizing which is perfectly working except when the mouse go out of the container then the inner exceed bot outer and container !! :(

Comment: Do you have a code example somewhere or could you make one with http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have the draggable & resizable layer together.. And it let the resize happen beyond the parent container... How can we fix that?